# Sitecore and Glassmapper auto-code (TDS code gen)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sitecore8

In Sitecore8.0, I have created a template, in which one of the field has field type as "Name Lookup Value List". And using "Sync with Sitecore", template was created in Visual Studio
I am using TDS to automatically generate my models for this. After re-generating code, I am getting build error which says:
"The type or namespace name 'Collections' does not exist in the namespace 'abc.Model.sitecore.templates.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Can anyone please guide me for the same?

Comment: Also I tried to install "System.Collections.Specialized 4.3.0", but I could not as my Nuget client server is v2.8

Comment: Sounds like you have created and/or checked some templates into the `/sitecore/templates/system` section. I suggest you a) don't touch any templates located there and b) move your owm templates to a different section.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your quick response!

I have created the template in "User Defined" section, but still I am getting the same build error.

Comment: Given the error message you are seeing, check you do not have a custom template called System... not sure otherwise with a lot more details of the setup. Provide details of your templates, VS project setup and CodeGen settings.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say what happens in your specific case, but there are 2 options here:

**1) You need to add using statement in your code generation template GlassV3Header.tt to System.Collections**

[image]

**2) NameValueCollection type is conflicting with other type.
Then you can add alias to the type and then reference the type for the field in CustomData property of TDS.**

```
using CustomNameValueCollection = System.Collections.NameValueCollections
```

[image]